# PowerShell Get-Content cannot access the file

Tags: powershell, wamp

I have monitoring logs from wamp server with windows terminal and command

```
Get-Content "C:\wamp64\logs\php_error.log" -Wait
```

But for some reason now is stopped to work and i can't find where is problem.

When i start PowerShell and command i can see content of php_error.log but when wamp start writing/append new content in php_error.log i have this error

```
Get-Content : The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content "C:\wamp64\logs\php_error.log" -Wait
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\wamp64\logs\php_error.log:String) [Get-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Comment: Close WinAmp and it should work fine.

Comment: It's not Winamp, it's a Wamp Server

Comment: since the app that makes the file has taken a lock on the file ... you are stuck with that. either wrap the call in a try-catch block or use some other error handler method.

Answer (score 0):

Get-Content tries to lock the file while reading and fails to lock because the file has already an lock. The solution is to use another method that lets you specify how you want to read that file and with what access-rights. Take a look at [this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1185141/1078160)